# How to capture "this" in a lambda function in lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

For example

```
class A
{
    void f() {}
    void g()
    {
        [this]() // Lambda capture this
        {
            f();
            A* p = this;
            [p]() // Workaround to let inner lambda capture this
            {
                p->f();
            };
        };
    }
};
```

Any better way to capture this in the inner lambda?

Comment: @JesseGood , others - this is not a dupe of the other question, since it's not about MSVS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `[=]`, this is implicitly captured. If you have other variables which you don't wanna capture by copy, then just capture `[this]`.

Comment: Just for understanding, why not `[&]`?

Comment: @bash.d: `this` can only be captured by copy, i.e. `[this]` or `[=]`.

Comment: @Jesse Good: `This` can be capture by reference.

Comment: @yngum no, this can't be captured by reference. That would mean doing [&this].

Comment: @bamboon `This` is just a pointer, why you cannot have a reference to a pointer. I tested the code and it capture `This` as a reference

Comment: @yngum: `this` is a prvalue (a temporary), you cannot have references to temporaries. [See example here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/230dyr$7) and error message: `error: 'this' cannot be captured by reference`.

Comment: use [=] is okay, but [this] does not work in VS2010.

Comment: @Jesse Good: [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/230dyr$19), I captured it as [&], &a will be equaled to a.g().

Comment: @yngum: Even with `[&]`, the code is implicity capturing `this` by copy.

Comment: @Jess Good: This is wierd but fair enough

Answer (score 5):

You could just re-capture `this`:

```
class A
{
    void f() {}
    void g()
    {
        [this]()
        {
            f();
            [this]()
        //   ^^^^
            {
                f();
            };
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: In my VS2010, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1899020: OK, didn't know you where using VS2010 so I didn't test it there. I guess the implementation of lambdas in VC10 is not compliant.

Comment: @user1899020 It seems that VS10 only supports Lambdas V1.0 and not V1.1, see here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx .